# 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' getting error while connecting to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am new to JavaScript and currently learning mongoDB with node and mongoose. when I try to connect
with db, i got this error:

Did you mean to import ../config/dbConfig.js?
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:255:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:908:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Please let me know where i did wrong and how to correct it in async & await?

`dbconfig.js`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', () => {
    console.log('Error in connection to Database');
});

connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Database')
});

module.exports = mongoose;
```

`index.js`

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
import mongoose from './config/dbConfig';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is over engineered, connecting with mongoose is a fairly straightforward process. You seem to be using ES Module syntax so you can't really mix `require()` and `import` together so I will provide an example using ES Module syntax. Please note that in future you need to provide a file extension to **your** modules that you import, i.e. you need to include the `.js` file extension.

```js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import 'dotenv/config';
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI).then(() => {
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a object mongoose connect and return it in dbconfig.js. In index.js, you use this object to startup app and connect db. Example:

**dbconfig.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const logger = require('./logger');

function makeNewConnection(uri) {
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    emitDbEvent(db);
    return db;
}

function emitDbEvent(connection) {
    connection.on('error', function (error) {
        logger.info(`database:: connection ${this.name} ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        connection.close().catch(() => console.log(`MongoDB :: failed to close connection ${this.name}`));
    });

    connection.on('connected', function () {
        logger.info(`database:: connected ${this.name}`);
    });

    connection.on('disconnected', function () {
        logger.info(`database:: disconnected ${this.name}`);
    });
}

const connectMongo = makeNewConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI);

module.exports = {
    connectMongo,
};
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const { connectMongo } = require('./dbconfig');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

await connectMongo();

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Comment: as i learnt await is only valid in async functions